# Add to Favourite?

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

I am creating a [Foodpanda](https://www.foodpanda.com/) type website through Craft Commerce where I want any logged user to be able to add any restaurant in his favourite list. And which will also show in User->Accounts->Favourite.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a custom plugin. [The Craft Slack](https://craftcms.com/community) has a #plugindev channel, if you fancy having a go yourself, and a #jobs channel, if you would prefer to hire someone. Feel free to DM me if you have any questions (@monooso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have very similar functionality working with Commerce on https://imagescience.com.au/ using the Shortlist plugin - any product or article can be favourited by logged in users.

It's really just two simple parts:

- a single macro for anywhere I want to add the option (adds a
  clickable star icon that add that uses an ajax call to add that entry
  to their shortlist)
- a `dashboard/favourites` template that iterates through the shortlist
  and separates out products and articles into two groups, then prints
  pretty lists of those things (with a remove button for each).

[Shortlist](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/shortlist) works well in practise for precisely this functionality and it is simple to implement exactly what you're looking for with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad, so I'll try to hone in on the core of it...

There are a few plugins which can help you get the "favorite" mechanics working. Regardless of which one you choose, you'll probably need to customize your specific implementation to fit the needs of your site.

- [Curate](https://github.com/lorigoldberg/curate)
- [Shortlist](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/shortlist)
- [Upvote](https://craftpl.us/plugins/upvote) *(disclaimer: I wrote it)*
- [Like](https://github.com/dukt/craft-like)